# Android: User Interface: LinearGradient not working with custom colors

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, linear-gradients

I am trying to add linear gradient to the text in my TextView using Shader and LinearGradient. This is working only if I use standard colors like Color.LTGRAY, Color.MAGENTA, etc. No gradient is shown if I use colors from my custom_colors.xml. Any ideas how can I make this work for custom colors?

```
Shader txtShad=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 10, new int[]{R.color.el_amethyst,R.color.el_maroon}, null, TileMode.MIRROR);
textview_dummy.getPaint().setShader(txtShad);
```

Below is the custom_colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="el_maroon">#CD2990</color>
  <color name="el_amethyst">#9D6B84</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Shader txtShad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 10, new int[] { getResources().getColor(R.color.el_amethyst), getResources().getColor(R.color.el_maroon) }, null, TileMode.MIRROR);
```

TL;DR you need to resolve the color resources first